# discord js how to sort json file money by descending

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

I try to sort a money in my json file but every time i get "money.slice is not a function"
can someone help with this? "money.sort((a,b)=>{b.money - a.money});" dont work to
My JSON file:

```
{"2858236346346":{"name":"user1","money":100}}, {"346342356347436":{"name":"user2","money":1000}}
```

The Code I have trouble with:

```
execute(client, message, args) {

    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./money.json');
    let money = JSON.parse(rawdata);
    console.log(money);

    const res = money.slice().sort((a, b) => b.money - a.money);
    console.log(res);

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Najbogatsi Gracze")
    //if there are no results
    if (res.length === 0) {
      embed.setColor("RED");
      embed.setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/pWHpi7G.png");
      embed.addField("Nie znaleziono danych", "Wpisz na czacie $daily aby zdobyć pieniądze!")
    } else if (res.length < 10) {
      //less than 10 results
      embed.setColor("BLURPLE");
      embed.setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/pWHpi7G.png");
      for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(res[i].id) || "Brak danych"
        if (member === "Brak danych") {
          embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member}`, `**Kasa:**: ${res[i].money}zł`);
        } else {
          embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member.user.username}`, `**Kasa:**: ${res[i].money}zł`);
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I just figured it out we must use loop and define new "const" in this case "res = [];" so then we can push a new json and then sort it

```
let money = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./money.json", "utf8"));

    const res = [];

  for(let userID in money){
    res.push({"id": userID, "money": money[userID].money })
    res.sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[1] - Object.values(a)[1])
    console.log(money, res);
}
```